# using pandas to read Excel file problem with xlrd module

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, xlrd

I am using python 3.9.1 with Spyder 4.2.1 on a Win 10. I can read CSV files using pandas, no problem. the code below executes correctly.

```
import pandas as pd
result = pd.read_csv('data.txt')
print(result.head())
```

but when i try with an excel file i get a 'missing xlrd dependancy error'.

```
import pandas as pd
twb = pd.read_excel("Data_Reports.xlsx")
print(twb.head())

ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.
```

xlrd is already installed in the python39\Lib folder.

```
Requirement already satisfied: xlrd in c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (2.0.1)
```

If i import xlrd,

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
twb = pd.read_excel("Data_Reports.xlsx")
print(twb.head())
```

i get a Module not found error.

```
File "C:\Users\myName\Documents\Python\Excel Examples\ReadingExcelFile01.py", line 2, in <module>
    import xlrd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlrd'
```

Can anyone help? Is it a path issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try doing `pip install xlrd` again and you don't have to import the module xlrd
If you already tried this , maybe update the packages in your IDE. If you are using anaconda type `conda deactivate` first and then `conda update --all`.

Comment: Thanks, deactivating & updating anaconda worked when i open spyder from anaconda. however if i open spyder outside of anaconda (downloaded separately from spyder website) , the error remains. Is there a pip command to do the same? i tried 'pip deactivate' but it gives an unknown error.

Comment: try doing `pip3 install xlrd` in seperate spyder thing @tmh

Comment: I tried that ``pip3 install xlrd`` but still no joy. Requirement already satisfied. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

**This is because your required libraries are been installed in Python environment instead of Spyder**

To fix this you can look for the solution mentioned in the below link.

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder